# Who is the character who said he built the time axis in "X-Men: The Animated Series"?

Tags: marvel, x-men, character-identification, x-men-the-animated-series

In *S04E11: Beyond Good and Evil Part 4* of *X-Men: The Animated Series*, there was a guy who said that he built the time axis. What is his name? I couldn't find any info about him.

Comment: https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0751304/fullcredits?ref_=tt_cl_sm#cast

Comment: http://marvel.wikia.com/wiki/X-Men:_The_Animated_Series_Season_4_11

Answer (score 12):

This guy?

[image]

He's Bender, a guardian of time, though

> at the end of the episode he's revealed to be Immortus, a time-manipulating villain.

(**warning: other spoilers ahead**, but I don't think this answer should be an all-hidden one.)

Long story short, Kang the Conqueror is a guy from the 30th century who came across a time-travelling technology. He went back in time to the pharaohs, presented himself as one and tried to make friends with En Sabah Nur (aka Apocalypse, aka most OP'ed mutant ever. Of all time). Now for the fun part: depending on which comic you're reading, Immortus is either Kang himself or an alternate version of him (as comics go...).

Powers: technically speaking, he doesn't have powers, but he's both a physics and strategy genius. Also, he's got a lot of future technology available, granting him what I call "superhuman starter pack": superhuman strength, increased defense, energy blasts, and some other nice things.

Comment: I always wanted to know who this guy is also, so thank you! I don't remember an explanation of his identity at the end of the episode, though.

Comment: @theguest probably because there wasn't. [He's shown as his true self and teleports away](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vhOKQ5_yc9E&feature=youtu.be&t=17m15s), never to be seen again in the show. What I described is taken from the paper comics.

Comment: Ok, thank you. I didn't remember that scene either. I'm happy that I finally know who he was.

Comment: @theguest my bad then. What I meant is that, we see him in what comic-book readers will remember to be his traditional outfit, and non-readers will probably guess that someone who hid his identity throughout the episode isn't necessarily a good guy, while not knowing exactly who it is.

Comment: Hey, he doesn't have a shiny metal ass!

Comment: @RDFozz not included in the superhuman starter pack, sorry ;) or were you thinking of something else? (Not being ironic here)

Comment: @Jenayah - Must've been thinking of a different [Bender](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bender_(Futurama))....